# Internet Explorer: Logging URLs to the Console with AutoIt

Tags: internet-explorer, com, autoit

I am using [autoit](http://autoitscript.com/) to run Internet Explorer.  I want IE to log all urls it visits in the console window.  When I compile this script, I compile it to run with a console window in the background.

```
#include <IE.au3>

ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", "about:blank")
WinWait("Blank Page")
$oIE = _IEAttach("about:blank", "url")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.dell.com")
$oEvt = ObjEvent($oIE, "_IEEvent_")

While 1
    Sleep(5000)
WEnd

; BeforeNavigate2 method definition
Func _IEEvent_BeforeNavigate2($IEpDisp, $IEURL, $IEFlags, $IETargetFrameName, $IEPostData, $IEHeaders, $IECancel)
    ConsoleWrite("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!--BeforeNavigate2 fired--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " & @CRLF & _
            "$IEpDisp = " & $IEpDisp() & "  -  " & ObjName($IEpDisp) & @CRLF & _ ; e.g. default property and name for the object
            "$IEURL = " & $IEURL & @CRLF & _
            "$IEFlags = " & $IEFlags & @CRLF & _
            "$IETargetFrameName = " & $IETargetFrameName & @CRLF & _
            "$IEPostData = " & $IEPostData & @CRLF & _
            "$IEHeaders = " & $IEHeaders & @CRLF & _
            "$IECancel = " & $IECancel & @CRLF & _
            "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " & @CRLF & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>_IEEvent_BeforeNavigate2
```

My problem is that nothing is displayed in the console when I surf with this instance of IE.  What am I doing wrong?

### FINAL SOLUTION

As Manadar suggested I changed to the following; this code throws an error on the console: `--> IE.au3 V2.4-0 Warning from function _IEAttach, $_IEStatus_NoMatch`, but it is purely cosmetic.

```
#Region ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Change2CUI=y
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_requestedExecutionLevel=asInvoker
#EndRegion ;**** Directives created by AutoIt3Wrapper_GUI ****

#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("about:blank", 1)
$oEvt = ObjEvent($oIE, "_IEEvent_", "DWebBrowserEvents2")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.cisco.com")

; Keep the console window open and poll with Sleep()
While 1
    Sleep(5)
WEnd

; BeforeNavigate2 method definition
Func _IEEvent_BeforeNavigate2($IEpDisp, $IEURL, $IEFlags, $IETargetFrameName, $IEPostData, $IEHeaders, $IECancel)
    $message = "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!--BeforeNavigate2 fired--!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! " & @CRLF & _
            "$IEpDisp = " & $IEpDisp() & "  -  " & ObjName($IEpDisp) & @CRLF & _
            "$IEURL = " & $IEURL & @CRLF & _
            "$IEFlags = " & $IEFlags & @CRLF & _
            "$IETargetFrameName = " & $IETargetFrameName & @CRLF & _
            "$IEPostData = " & $IEPostData & @CRLF & _
            "$IEHeaders = " & $IEHeaders & @CRLF & _
            "$IECancel = " & $IECancel & @CRLF & _
            "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" & @CRLF & @CRLF
    ConsoleWrite($message)
EndFunc   ;==>_IEEvent_BeforeNavigate2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of functions is wrong in your code. ObjEvent should be called before you _IENavigate! Otherwise when you navigate, the event is not yet attached. On top of that, the ObjEvent function needs "DWebBrowserEvents2" as the third parameter.

Your code will look like this:

```
#include <IE.au3>

ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", "about:blank")
WinWait("Blank Page")
$oIE = _IEAttach("about:blank", "url")

$oEvt = ObjEvent($oIE, "_IEEvent_", "DWebBrowserEvents2")
_IELoadWait($oIE)
_IENavigate($oIE, "http://www.dell.com")
```

Don't forget to add the while, sleep and function back yourself.

You should also instead of:

```
ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", "about:blank")
WinWait("Blank Page")
$oIE = _IEAttach("about:blank", "url")
```

Do this:

```
$oIE = _IECreate("about:blank", 1)
```

Comment: Ok, I edited my question to reflect your suggestion (so you know what I'm running).  After re-compiling and running the binary, now I see `--> IE.au3 V2.4-0 Warning from function _IEAttach, $_IEStatus_NoMatch` on the console when I start the application.  Any thoughts on where the problem is?

Comment: This is normal behavior from _IECreate with second parameter 1. It tries first to attach to a window which is open on the specified url ("about:blank" in this case), when it doesn't find the window it will give a warning and then open the page. You can turn off this warning behavior with _IEErrorNotify.

Comment: I got it to work... you can check the diffs to see what I changed after I sent the last message

Comment: Your final script looks good. Note that the Sleep(5) might as well be Sleep(10000) as the ObjEvent function will interrupt a running sleep.